# Inheritence Class Design (in Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, class-design

for a small game I want to design two classes which should draw my Units. I have the classes `Unit` and `Settler` which extends `Unit`.

To draw them I have the classes `UnitView` and `SettlerView`.

Now `UnitView` has a method `public void draw(Graphics g)` and `SettlerView` should use the same method. The difference in the two classes should be in the way they are getting the information to draw the Unit. Let's say `Units` are allways blue and `Settlers` have a Color depending on their health (which would be a field in `Settler`, where `SettlerView` has access to).

What would be a proper way to implement that? I want a clean design without public methods like `setColor`.

edit: This was my first approach:

```
public class UnitView {
    private Unit unit;
    public Color color; // I don't want to make it public. Setting it private + getter/setter does not seem to be different to me.
    private color calculateColor() { ...uses the information of unit... }
    public void draw(Graphics g) { ...something using the Color... }

}

public class SettlerView extends UnitView {
    private Settler settler;

    private color calculateColor() { ...this method overides the one of UnitView.... }
}
```

I want to use Polymorphism to call UnitView.draw. The key thing is the public field Color.

Comment: Accessors and mutators for member variables are key to encapsulation and are part of a clean design. You shouldn't be trying to avoid them.

Comment: Create interface IView containing draw() method, have UnitView and SettlerView implement IView.  Anywhere you are using a *View, use the IView interface.  Since an interface cannot have fields, you must create an accessor method getColor() and add it to the IView interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always override the parent draw method.

so for example if parent method is

```
public void draw(Graphic g){
     g.setColor(blue);
}
```

the child class will have

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphic g){        
    if  (this.health > 50){
        g.setColor(green);
    }else{
        g.setColor(red);
    }
    super.draw(g); // if you want to call the parent draw and just change color
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Assume that draw(Graphic g) is a complicated function and I want to use the parentclass implementation, because only the color has changed.

Comment: use super.draw inside  the child draw

Comment: But how does it know about the changed color then?

Comment: you can either redraw it with different color and have the draw method pick the color depending on the health, or you can put a change color method that just changes the color depending on the health. I would go with adding a method just to change the color but you pointed that you would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about polymorphism:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

UnitView and SettlerView should derive from a base class with a draw() method.  You can make it abstract so that all subclasses must implement it.